Does the radius of the inner circle have a specific ratio to the outer construction?
I am studying the underlying proportions in some arabesque patterns described in the YouTube video "Lesson 4, Starting with a more complex Islamic Art Pattern" by bassem zawdeh, and I stumbled upon the following construction:


the inner red circle is tangent to the red line going through R;
the inner squares have $\sqrt{2}/2$ side;
the slope of the red line depends thus on the inner squares side, being $CR = \sqrt{2}/2$.

I tried some calculations, but no "interesting" numbers came from it - I could post them after having double checked them, since it was the result of multiple rationalisations.
The drawing software on the other hand evaluates the radius to be 0.12, that seems too good to be true!
Am I missing something obvious?

If you embed your drawing into a Cartesian coordinate system, you can derive the equation that describes the red line. You have one point on the line $(x_0,y_0)=\left(-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\right)$ and the equation of the line is
$$
\frac{y-y_0}{x-x_0}=m
$$
So you get
$$
\frac{y+\frac{1}{2}}{x+\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
$$
Now you can transform this into the Hesse normal form from which you can directly  read the distance of the line to the origin, which is the radius of the inner circle.
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{y+\frac{1}{2}}{x+\frac{1}{2}} & =& \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \\
y+\frac{1}{2} & =& \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right) \\
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} x - y & = & \frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4} \\
\frac{\sqrt{6}}{2}
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} \\
-\frac{\sqrt{6}}{3}
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{pmatrix}
 & = & \frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{4} \\
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} \\
-\frac{\sqrt{6}}{3}
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{pmatrix}
 & = & \frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{2\sqrt{6}} \\
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} \\
-\frac{\sqrt{6}}{3}
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{pmatrix}
 & = & \frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{3}}{6} \approx 0,119573
\end{eqnarray}

The exact value is $\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\approx0.11957\ ,$ which you can find by chasing various similar triangles round the diagram, as illustrated in the figure below, in which I've labelled the intersections of the line $DR$ (i.e. the red line) with the lines $OG$ and $OH$ with $W$ and $Z$, respectively.  The lengths labelling various line segments in the diagram can be obtained in the following sequence:
\begin{align}
|GB|&=|CB|-|CG|\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{2}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\\
|HZ|&=|DH|\times\text{ slope of red line}\\
&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\\
|ZO|&=|HO|-|HZ|\\
&=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\ .
\end{align}
Now triangles $OWZ$ and $GWB$ are similar.  Therefore
\begin{align}
\frac{|OW|}{|GW|}&=\frac{|OZ|}{|GB|}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\ ,\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}
and we also have
\begin{align}
|OW|+|GW|&=|OG|\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\ .\tag{2}\label{2}
\end{align}
Equations \eqref{1} and \eqref{2} give us two easily solved linear equations for the quantities $\ |OW|\ $ and $\ |GW|\ $ which give us
\begin{align}
|OW|&=\frac{1}{2\big(1+\sqrt{2}\big)}\ \ \text{ and}\\
|GW|&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\big(1+\sqrt{2}\big)}\ .
\end{align}
Applying Pythagoras's theorem to the triangle $\ GWB\ $ gives
\begin{align}
|WR|&=\sqrt{|GW|^2+|GR|^2}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\big(1+\sqrt{2}\big)}\ .
\end{align}
Now triangles $OTW$ and $RGW$ are similar, and therefore
\begin{align}
\frac{|TO|}{|GR|}&=\frac{|WO|}{|WR|}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\ .
\end{align}
This gives
\begin{align}
|TO|&=\frac{|GR|}{\sqrt{3}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\ ,
\end{align}
which is the radius of the inner circle.


Let the radius of the big circle be $r$ (so that the side of the square is $2r$), and the radius of the inner target circle be $s$. Let $R'$ and $R''$ be reflections of $R$ in the horizontal axis and center of the square.

A little angle-chasing shows that $\triangle BOR'$ is $45^\circ$-$67.5^\circ$-$67.5^\circ$, hence isosceles, whence $|BR'|=|BO|=r\sqrt{2}$ and $|CR'|=|BC|-|BR'|=r(2-\sqrt{2})$. Note also that $BR''$, the hypotenuse of a right triangle with legs $2r$ and $r\sqrt{2}$, has length $r\sqrt{6}$.
Finally, observe that $\square CDR''R'$ and $\square RDR''B$, as parallelograms sharing base $DR''$ and height $2r$, have equal areas; since the latter is also a parallelogram with base $BR''$ and height $2s$, we can equate calculations of those areas thusly
$$\begin{align}
|\square RDR''B| \;&=\; |\square CDR''R'|  \\[6pt]
\to\quad 2s\cdot r\sqrt{6} \;&=\; 2r\cdot r(2-\sqrt{2}) \\[6pt]
\to\quad \frac{s}{2r} \;&=\; \frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{2\sqrt{6}} = 0.1195\ldots
\end{align}$$
confirming OP's approximation and other answers' exact calculations. $\square$
